# AM/GM inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, tangent-line-method, muirhead-inequality

I need some help to prove this inequality... I guess one can use Jensen's then AM/GM inequalities.

Let $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ be non- negative real numbers such that
$x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 =1$.
We want to show that
$$x_1^3 + x_2^3 + x_3^3 + x_4^3 \ge x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4,$$
and also
$$x_1^3 + x_2^3 + x_3^3 + x_4^3 \ge \frac1{x_1}+ \frac1{x_2} +\frac1{x_3}+\frac1{x_4}.$$

Since $x↦x^3$ is convex on R+ by Jensen's Inequality we have $x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3+x_4^3≥4^{-2}(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)^3$ then using AM/GM inequality and since $x_1x_2x_3x_4=1,$ we can show that $(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)^3≥4$

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: The second: multiply RHS by $x_1x_2x_3x_4$ and then apply [Muirhead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead%27s_inequality#Another_equivalent_condition). The first should be killable in this way too: square both parts, multiply RHS by $x_1x_2x_3x_4$ and then apply Muirhead.

Comment: @Clifford I solved your problems. If you want to see my solutions show please your attempts.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Since $x \mapsto x^3$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}^+$ by Jensen's Inequality we have $x_1^3 + x_2^3 + x_3^3 + x_4^3 \ge 4^{-2} (x_1 + x_2 + x_3 +  x_4)^3 $  then using AM/GM inequality and since $x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 = 1$, we can show that $ (x_1 + x_2 + x_3 +  x_4)^3 \ge 4$

Answer (score 5):

> $\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n x_i=1,x_i\in\mathbb R^+$.
> Show that
>
> - $(a)\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n x_i^3\ge \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^nx_i$
> - $(b)\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n x_i^3\ge \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{x_i}$

$(a)$ Let $f(x)=x^3-x$. Since $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x)=6x>0\ \forall\ x>0$, Jensen's inequality $$\Rightarrow \dfrac{\displaystyle\sum _{i=1}^n(x^3_i-x_i)}n\ge f\left(\frac{\displaystyle\sum x_i}n\right)\ge f\left(\left(\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^{\frac1n}\right)=f(1)=0\tag{1}$$
since $f(x)$ is increasing after $x=1$.

**PS:** Draw graph of $f(x)$ to understand it better.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}x^{-3}<0$ for $x>0$. Also I think you're missing a cube around the right side of the inequality in $(a)$ when using Jensen. That conclusion is clearly false without some kind of further assumption. E.g. take $x_1=\ldots=x_n=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: It's highly doubtful that $(x^{-3})'>0$ as $(x^{-3})'=\color{red}-3x^{-4}$

Comment: @halrankard I don't know what has happened to my eyes today. It's double derivative. Sorry!

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Is my solution correct now? I am afraid because it's been a while since I last did questions like these...

Comment: I don't see what form of Jensen is happening in $(a)$. But still, if you propose to prove $(a)$ without using some extra assumption like $x_{1} \ldots x_{n} = 1$ then you will fail as illustrated by the example $x_{i} = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Maybe you mean to write $f((\sum x_i)/n)$ not $f(1)/n$? Then you do use the extra assumption via AM/GM?

Comment: @Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SameerBaheti it's still unclear where $f(1)$ and $g(1)$ came from so I can't say by [this revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3760275/4) whether it;s correct or not, sorry)

Comment: IMO "RHS has the minimum value" is unclear. It was clear (and correct) when you simply wrote an inequality in (a). But (b) does not appear correct. If $a=\sum y_i/n$ and $b=(\prod y_i)^{1/n}$ then  $a\geq b$ so $g(a)\leq g(b)=0$ (I assume this is what you mean by "$g(a)$ has the maximum value $g(b)$"). So there is not enough to conclude LHS of (2) is $\geq 0$.

Comment: @halrankard Yeah I am myself figuring that out rn.

Comment: FWIW this is a clever solution to (a) (although if I had my way AM/GM would be mentioned explicitly!). You end up proving a stronger inequality in this case, which maybe suggests a Jensen approach to (b) won't work.

Comment: @halrankard It works for $(b)$ for $x>\frac1{3^{1/4}}$, which is after the point of inflection.

Comment: I assume that's the inflection point where $x^3-x^{-1}$ becomes convex? Then, yes I agree.

Answer (score 3):

The first inequality.

We need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}x_1^3\geq\sum_{cyc}x_1\sqrt{\prod_{cyc}x_1}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}x_1^3\geq\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{x_1^3x_2x_3x_4},$$which  is true by Muirhead because
$$(3,0,0,0)\succ(1.5,0.5,0.5,0.5).$$
We can use also AM-GM:
$$\sum_{cyc}x_1^3=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{cyc}(3x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3+x_4^3)\geq\frac{1}{6}\sum_{cyc}6\sqrt[6]{x_1^9x_2^3x_3^3x_4^3}=\sum_{cyc}x_1.$$
Also, the Tangent Line method works:
$$\sum_{cyc}(x_1^3-x_1)=\sum_{cyc}\left(x_1^3-x_1-2\ln{x_1}\right)\geq0.$$
Indeed, let $f(x)=x^3-x-2\ln{x},$ where $x>0$.

Thus, $$f'(x)=3x^2-1-\frac{2}{x}=\frac{(x-1)(3x^2+3x+2)}{x},$$ which gives $x_{min}=1$, $$f(x)\geq f(1)=0$$ and we are done!

The second inequality we can prove by similar ways.